# Driver for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that supports GTX 1050 TI graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, 64-bit, budgie

Can anyone tell me if Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS has an open source driver that supports an NVIDIA Gtx 1050 ti graphics card?

My CPU is an Intel E2140.

Comment: Thanks all for answering to me!I need to know too if I can install this proprietary NVIDIA graphic driver without a graphic card cause I will buy it yet.Then,for a while I need to keep my current driver that is a "llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)".My computer don't have an offboard graphic card and his motherboard is a Gigabyte VM900M (rev.1).Thanks CentaurusA to correct me...As you can see I'm a newbie here.

Comment: Organic Marble,I typed this and that was the result:

Comment: nvidia-settings:
  Instalado: 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Candidato: 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     390.42-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: This appears to show that you have installed nvidia, at least the settings part.  What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: When I go to Software and Updates and check in additional drivers if I have an option to chose a driver, my system don't find any driver.I think that even I  have not bought a graphic card yet,this should be appear in additional driver option at least without a possibility to mark it.

Comment: Are you saying you do not yet have a graphics card installed? Because I have no idea how it would work in that case.

Comment: So,when I buy a gtx 1050 ti my OS will auto recognize this hardware and then make NVIDIA driver available?

Comment: I cannot know exactly what will happen with your particular case. My answer tells you exactly what I did and shows you that it worked.

Comment: Whatever if it will works in the future or not,thank you for your tips and when I install a graphic card in my computer I will notice the result here to we know if it works or not.I just wait a discount in the regular price of this card now,maybe I'll buy this in January...I don't get why in my country these things are so expensive!

Comment: I'm coming here to tell my new situation.When I did a download of a graphic card,even though my system doesn't detect any graphic driver yet,I've been notice that I have installed a software named NVIDIA X Server Settings.I don't know if it will works when I buy a NVIDIA graphic card.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/785762/186740 this was the simplest way around the whole issue without adding ppa sources

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The proprietary Nvidia graphics driver can be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 from the terminal with the following commands:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
sudo reboot
```

When installing a proprietary graphics driver, it is not necessary to uninstall the built-in open source graphics driver. The two graphics drivers can be installed alongside each other allowing the  open source graphics driver to be used as a fallback alternative in case there is a problem using the proprietary graphics driver.

The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies, and the Nvidia driver will also be updated automatically when an update is available.

Comment: Karel,I have typed this command in Tilix and then it said "No drivers found for automatic installation." I think I'd better install this from NVIDIA site,so I'll try do it...I don't know exactly what to do now.But Thanks for your anwser! :)

Comment: It definitely looks like the NVIDIA driver is supported for this graphic card in Organic Marble's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The attached screenshot shows that the NVIDIA 390.87 driver is running my GeForce GTX 1050 Ti card.

I installed this driver from the `graphics-drivers` ppa thusly:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-384 nvidia-settings
```

Note: this is what I did, and 384 is supposedly a transitional package; you may be able to install nvidia-390 directly.

[image]

Comment: Hello Organic Marble!Thanks for your anwser! However I didn't get a driver yet by these commands.Maybe my kernel don't accept the driver cause my old machine that that is a Gigabyte VM900M.Do you know if someone have installed NVIDIA proprietary driver on an old motherboard like mine?My Ubuntu says to me that I don't have any additional driver available.

Comment: if you type 'apt policy nvidia-settings' in a terminal and [edit] your question to include the result, I may have other suggestions.

Comment: @J-Mello The problem is not installing the driver. The driver exists and it works. But newer cards can't possibly work in a 2006 computer.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I agree and I know that my old computer will not run a graphics card like these newer as good as it would be cause the lower power of a 2 core cpu with only 1,2ghz!I'm looking for a 2018/2019 computer that I'll build buying each hardware component like i9 9900k,Gigabyte Z390, 32gb ram...with an amazing Cougar case.Then,my screen will not freeze anymore and certainly I will able to enjoy each feature of Ubuntu and grow up in Ubuntu and Linux community! :)