# Why videos and scrolling have a low frame buffering(freezing) on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS and how to fix this?

Tags: 18.04, video, 64-bit, framebuffer

Unfortunately,since I moved to this linux distro my screen has a buffering issue when I use whatever kind of browser and when I play any video with or without a browser.The screen runs like chopped up or freezing(I don't know if buffer is the same as freezing,but its certainly freezing,videos are running like taking pictures every 2 seconds).I need to know if have a solution to this issue by a properly software for linux cause I don't want to buy a graphic card now.Thanks! PS:My motherboard is a Gigabyte VM900M(rev.1).

Comment: I have a llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits) graphic driver installed by default.

Comment: LLVM means software rendering - which usually means there isnt a detected dedicated graphics driver detected - hence why videos are slow.  Are there any graphics drivers displayed in Software Updater - Settings - Additional Drivers tab ?

Comment: @fossfreedom No,my system doesn't detect any graphic driver.I have a topic about this here:(https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078964/driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-that-supports-gtx-1050-ti-graphics-card?noredirect=1#comment1773196_1078964) .The point here is a software like 3DAnalyzer on windows that renderize another software that needs a better performance of hardware to run properly.Thanks to answering for me! :)

Comment: I don't know if the meaning is the same as buffering...My screen is freezing!I've downloaded adobe flash player and nothing happens!

Comment: That's approx a 2006 motherboard?  VIA graphics?  Not very well supported in a linux world ... and a very old computer.  Suggest Lubuntu will be a better fit for old computers ... a better graphics card will definitely help here.

Comment: So,do you know if I buy a gtx 1050 ti for this motherboard it will definitely works properly?Meanwhile,at the last chance, I'll try to install swiftshader as a "renderize plus".Probably it wil not works...But I remember that in windows this software have performed miracles! I wanna use my current system with this graphic card! Thanks to answering for me! :)

Comment: nvidia?  Haven't heard of anything specifically that will not work with it.  Benchmarks here https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia-gtx-1050ti&num=1

Comment: NVIDIA is calling me to buy her! So,gtx 1050 ti is coming to my system.My dream is jump to RTX 2080 ti after cause I'm building a super computer with a lot of performance and beauty! I've just bought a beautiful multilaser warrior mouse! I'd like to buy a gtx 1050 ti before a keyboard! Thanks for your tips! :)

Comment: You won't be able to use newer graphics with such old machine.